# Removing of warning Msg

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am new to r coding. trying to automate some workings.but facing some issue..just a warning msg..

```
> First.Platoon<-c(6895)
> Second.Platoon<-c(6895)
> Third.Platoon<-c(6895)
> org_platoon_count=data.frame(First.Platoon,Second.Platoon,Third.Platoon)
> org_platoon_count
  First.Platoon Second.Platoon Third.Platoon
1          6895           6895          6895
```

now i have a data set like

```
> table(borugh16thmay$Platoon)

 First Platoon Second Platoon  Third Platoon 
          6895           6895           6895
```

when i am trying to compare the both data by all command it gives warnings like..

```
> all(org_platoon_count,table(borugh16thmay$Platoon))
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In all(c(6895, 6895, 6895), c(6895L, 6895L, 6895L), na.rm = FALSE) :
  coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

pls help me to remove the warning msg...

I tried

```
all.equal(org_platoon_count,table(borugh16thmay$Platoon)) 
[1] "Modes: list, numeric" 
[2] "Names: 3 string mismatches" 
[3] "Attributes: < Names: 1 string mismatch >" 
[4] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 2 components >" 
[5] "Attributes: < Component “class”: 1 string mismatch >" 
[6] "Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 2 >" 
[7] "current is not list-like"
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. If the goal is to compare the table output to to original data.frame, you may try `all.equal`. For you actual question, see `?suppressWarnings`.

Comment: Thanks @Imo for the quick response..yes what u say is right just tryng to compare that..but should i need to worry about it as it Display "TRUE" ..but with a warning msg.??

Comment: `all.equal(org_platoon_count,table(borugh16thmay$Platoon))
[1] "Modes: list, numeric"                                             
[2] "Names: 3 string mismatches"                                       
[3] "Attributes: < Names: 1 string mismatch >"                         
[4] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 2 components >"
[5] "Attributes: < Component “class”: 1 string mismatch >"             
[6] "Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 2 >"         
[7] "current is not list-like"`

Comment: `> mode(org_platoon_count) [1] "list"
> mode(table(borugh16thmay$Platoon)) [1] "numeric"` pls can you guide me to what to do to avoid this error??also if i convert mode of org_platoon_count dataset in neumeric then how to do it in this case??

Comment: It is quite difficult to read long blocks of code in comments. Please put updates or modifications in your question instead. Comparing a table object with a data.frame object will always result in a mismatch as their structure differs.